# Appending a DataFrame to another DataFrame, at a specific MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

In the following `DataFrame`, namely `df1`:

```
In[0]: df1
Out[0]:
                     A         B
first second                    
bar   one     1.764052  0.400157
      one     0.978738  2.240893
      one     1.867558 -0.977278
      two     0.950088 -0.151357
```

I wish to append another `DataFrame` *after the last row* of the MultiIndex `('bar','one')`, while giving the newly added lines *the same MultiIndex*.

That is, for the following `df2`:

```
In[1]: df2
Out[1]:

                     A         B
first second                    
baz   three  -0.103219  0.410599
      three   0.144044  1.454274
```

The desired result is:

```
                     A         B
first second                    
bar   one     1.764052  0.400157
      one     0.978738  2.240893
      one     1.867558 -0.977278
      one    -0.103219  0.410599   # there 2 rows
      one     0.144044  1.454274   #    arrived from df2
      two     0.950088 -0.151357
```

**So far is the question.**

Some of my unsuccessful attempts up ahead:

(1) Iterating by group (using `groupby`) and concating a new DataFrame based of `df2` values:

```
for idx, data in df1.groupby(level=[0,1]):
    df1.loc[idx] = pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(df2, index=idx)], ignore_index=True)

Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

*(Also tried placing them in a new `DataFrame`).*

(2) [reindexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df2` priorly:

```
for idx, data in df1.groupby(level=[0,1]):
    df2.reindex(idx)

Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Or:

```
for idx, data in df1.groupby(level=[0,1]):
    df2.index = idx
    break

            A         B
bar -0.103219  0.410599
one  0.144044  1.454274
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually insert data into an existing dataframe, you need to decide a couple of things.

1. Where are you going to insert it?  I figure this out by finding the first instance where the index is `('bar', 'one')`.
2. What are you going to call the data?  Put another way, what are the indexes of the data you are inserting?  Clearly, you are changing the index values.  You must know ahead of time what those index values are.  Unless you want it to inherit the index values of the row immediately preceding it (I'll show this too).

---

```
position = (df1.index.to_series() == ('bar', 'two')).values.argmax()

pd.concat([
        df1.iloc[:position],
        df2.set_index([['bar', 'bar'], ['one', 'one']]),
        df1.iloc[position:]
    ])
```

[image]

---

Example where new rows inherit index values from preceding row (results in same as above)

```
position = (df1.index.to_series() == ('bar', 'two')).values.argmax()
insert_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.index[[position - 1]].tolist() * len(df2))

pd.concat([
        df1.iloc[:position],
        df2.set_index(insert_idx),
        df1.iloc[position:]
    ])
```

Comment: @Merlin These are `True`s and `False`s.  `argmax()` finds the first `True`.  `argmin()` would find the first `False`.

Comment: @Merlin Ahh, I see what you are getting at.  That's why I used `argmax()` to get position of `('bar', 'two')`.  Then I'm inserting above it.  Still `argmin()`  would not insert to the bottom.  It would insert above the first `False`, which is the first `('bar', 'one')`

Comment: ('bar', 'one ') and argmin(), works for me, thats why I asked -- I didnt notice that you ('bar', 'two ').

Comment: @Merlin `np.array([1, 0, 0, 2]).argmin()` returns `1`.  Are you using `loc` or `iloc`?

Comment: using this and the rest of your answer position = (df1.index.to_series() == ('bar', 'one')).values.argmin()